# How to have vertical grid lines in QTableWidget?

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya, pyside2, qtablewidget

Right now I am using self.setShowGrid(False), but it completely removes the grid lines. So it's either all or nothing. But I want to have only vertical grid lines, not horizontal, like in the picture.

Is this possible? How to do this?

[image]

Comment: 1. It comes installed by default. 2. Yes. 3. I tried to run that but it crashed the program. I will try again. 4. There is a default stylesheet applied from the host app, I will try to get it and post it here.

Comment: 3. QStyleSheetStyle

Comment: Stylesheet is here: 1600 > lines of code. Should I post it in the OP? I will try what you said now. https://paste.ofcode dot org /399QJk8nYJWBUxjQ56fmZra

Comment: Actually it's another app called houdini but it's like maya, I will try your next suggestions now.

Comment: Yes, I am getting this error also using the same code:   File "<stdin>", line 6, in paint
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given) I will change to topleft now.

Comment: Same thing with topLeft so I assume the error is preventing the painting hence the drawing error and the lag while scrolling?

Comment: Oh yes it's python2, and also pyside2 version is 5.12.6.

Comment: Ok now I see the text content but also new error:   File "<stdin>", line 10, in paint
TypeError: a float is required
Qt Warn: QPainter::end: Painter ended with 45 saved states

Comment: Np you are right will do next time.

Comment: I updated it, what should I do with the latest error?

Comment: This time just say:   File "<stdin>", line 10, in paint
TypeError: a float is required, but printed many times.

Comment: Line 10 points to: painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(color, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))

Comment: wow now it works, thanks a lot. but is it safe to ignore all of these removals like painter.save/restore?

Comment: Oh yes now it works even with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to paint those lines using a delegate:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class VerticalLineDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        super(VerticalLineDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)
        line = QtCore.QLine(option.rect.topRight(), option.rect.bottomRight())
        color = option.palette.color(QtGui.QPalette.Mid)
        painter.save()
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(color))
        painter.drawLine(line)
        painter.restore()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 4)
    delegate = VerticalLineDelegate(w)
    w.setItemDelegate(delegate)
    w.setShowGrid(False)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I just tried this but I lost all the items but there is a scrollbar, and when I scroll it's lagging and there is no grid lines also. Why could this be?

Comment: @JoanVenge I don't see that problem, without a [mre] nor proof of what you indicate (perhaps some image that shows the problem that you observe) it is impossible for me to help you. My code adds draw the lines without modifying the underlying paint.

Comment: Ok let me try to isolate the issue.

Comment: Ok I run your code as is but it seems like the default stylesheet assigned seems to cause issues, but here is before and after I set item delegate using your method: https://imgur.com/a/nVuwb3c

Comment: @JoanVenge try changing to `color = QtGui.QColor("red")` and show me what you get. I'm still waiting for the MRE

Comment: I just did it, looks same: https://imgur.com/a/V2Qom1n

Comment: @JoanVenge With these tests I think you are not using my code correctly, so I will not try to help you until you provide the MRE.

Comment: @JoanVenge mmm, I don't see anything ... On the other hand, you should know that the MRE is the code that must be shown in your post.

Comment: That was imgur error, I reuploaded. I will update the post, but I am using your code.

Comment: @JoanVenge I do not want to argue unnecessarily, if you provide what I have asked then we would save the comments.